# Is it worth zeroing an XMM register for scalar one-input one-output instructions?

Tags: assembly, x86, simd, sse

Some SSE instructions take one scalar input for one scalar output, such as, `sqrtss`, `rsqrtss`, `rcpss`, ... These instructions don't change the upper bits of the output register, so I believe it has a dependency on the output register.

Is it worth putting an extra `xorps` to break the dependency when the output register of such an instruction is different from the input register?

Comment: Yes, if the false dependency is loop-carried or otherwise causes a problem in the surrounding context.  If your source operand was already in a register, you might consider `rsqrtps` to avoid that, if you want to write the result to a separate register so you keep the original around.  But for `sqrtps`, some CPUs (e.g. Alder Lake E-cores) have twice the throughput for `sqrtsd` vs. `sqrtpd`.  But only low-power CPUs, not big cores it seems; big cores only break things up in 128-bit chunks as far as getting more throughput out of wide dividers.

Comment: This seems like a duplicate, but were you intending to ask about advice for how to decide when on a case-by-case basis?  That could be a separate question from what compilers do, especially if the question linked the Q&A about what clang and GCC do, with clang only breaking false deps inside loops.

Comment: (And BTW, even as far back as Conroe on https://uops.info/, sqrtss has the same throughput as sqrtps for "big core" CPUs, also zen1 / zen2, it's only silvermont-family where everything slower, and 128-bit is half speed of scalar.  (eg. Alder-E has 24c sqrtpd, 12c sqrtsd throughput, partially pipelined so latency is even worse.  sqrtps/ss are twice as fast as their double equivalents on that CPU, so 6c throughput for sqrtss.  Older low-power like Goldmont really skimped on FPU hardware, like 67c throughput for sqrtpd / 19c sqrtss)